# What is jQuery version of this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jQuery I want to know what is the jQuery version of the JavaScript code below:

```
document
      .getElementById('cars')
      .addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false);
```

This is because jQuery doesn't like `addEventListener()`.

Comment: What have you tried? SO is not a free coding service. Start by learning jQuery: http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials

Comment: It's not jQuery. It's pure javascript

Comment: I tried the bind method before posting this question but it did not seem to work

Comment: @emi - true, this is why the OP is looking for a jQuery version.

Comment: Sorry the bind method does work, the mistake was that I put flase at the end of the change event. Thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That would be...

```
$('#cars').change(handleFileSelect);
```

jQuery **does** like `addEventListener()`. In fact, I'm certain it is the preferred implementation of its events (being the standard).

Answer (score 4):

```
$("#cars").bind("change",handleFileSelect)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('.#cars').change(handleFileSelect);
```

Broken Down:

```
// document.getElementById('cars')
$('#cars');                        // #<name> is id reference,
                                   // .<name> is class reference
                                   // <name> is an HTML tag reference

// addEventListener
.bind('change', handleFileSelect)  // "broad" binding
.change(handleFileSelect)          // jQuery short-hand of above
```

Answer (score 1):

Essentially your answer is this :

```
$("#files").bind("change",handleFileSelect);
```

However the `change` event is used by some other in-built event handlers so you might want to stay away from using that specific string as your event - unless of course you are looking to capture **that** event. :P

> The change event is sent to an element when its value changes. This
>   event is limited to `<input>` elements, `<textarea>` boxes and `<select>`
>   elements. For select boxes, checkboxes, and radio buttons, the event
>   is fired immediately when the user makes a selection with the mouse,
>   but for the other element types the event is deferred until the
>   element loses focus.

---

The [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) says this to describe the `bind` function :

> Attach a handler to an event for the elements.

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
$('#cars').bind('change', function() { //your code goes here });
```

According to jQuery docs:

http://api.jquery.com/bind/ (bind)

http://api.jquery.com/live/ (live)

Given the great number of choices, you must choose the clearer and that one who makes your understanding easily.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Note that `.live` is deprecated since jQuery 1.7.

Comment: Yup, only for studies purpose. Here goes the new one "on" method: http://api.jquery.com/on/ Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#cars").on('change', handleFileSelect);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$("#cars").live("change",handleFileSelect)
```

This will be helpful, if your input element is dynamically created by javascript.

Comment: You should merge this with your existing answer - it is not different enough to be in its own answer.

Comment: `live()` should not be recommended over `on()` these days.